# OutOfMemoryError before reaching the maximum of the heap space?

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am experiencing a very strange issue, which I would like to reproduce in a SSCCE, but I can't.

I am running my program in Java8 (32bits) with `-Xmx1024m`, this code is loading a pretty big file (120MB) into an array of bytes using a `FileInputStream`.

The problem is that, whereas in Java6 I had no problems, in Java8 I get `OutOfMemoryError` exceptions as soon as I try to load it.

I still have a lot of memory free, and I I have profiled it, and I see no problem.

If I try to extract out this problem in a SSCCE then it works.

I know that Oracle has got rid of the PermGen, but how that may be affecting my program?

I have also read that it might be related with a fragmentation problem of the heap space, but I tried to debug it, profile it, and run a GC cycle from the profiler just before allocating the memory, and it is still happening (I assume that a GC cycle would defragment the heap space)

Comment: first, check the message of the OOME, it doesn't have to be the heap space limitation. secondly, use a profiler, see what's consuming (more) memory.

Comment: it does not contain any message "null"

Comment: Running the same, with the same -Xmx1024m but in 64bits works.

Comment: When I active the -verbose:gc I see:
[GC (Allocation Failure) [DefNew: 216334K->4995K(314560K), 0.0130429 secs] 264354K->53015K(1013632K), 0.0130844 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
Again, why does it not go to the tenured pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have found the reason. According to this bug report:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6478546

`FileInputStream` reserves the space directly into the native memory. It is actually worse when increasing the size of the Max heap space, since there is actually less space for native maps.

The reason why my code works with Java8 64 bits, is precisely because I have more virtual space from Windows, and not constrained to ~1.7Gb in Windows.

It is still not very clear to me, why the same code works in Java6. It seems that the same application uses more native space in Java8 than in Java6. Perhaps the new scheme with Metaspace changed things a bit. I am not sure.

Interesting article about it:

http://www.codingthearchitecture.com/2008/01/14/jvm_lies_the_outofmemory_myth.html

Answer (score 4):

With Java8 there are some new things moved to heap which were part of PermGenSpace before, for example string pool, also check the size of old generation it allocates

Comment: In VisualGC, the Old Generation pool is still having 600MB free.

Comment: then you are probably trying to create an object which gets created first in young gen and young gen is too small for it

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thing.

- 1 GB isn't much, even on Windows 32 bit you can make it 1400 MB.
- Java 8 does work differently to Java 6 and it is optimised with the assumption that memory is cheaper than when Java 6 was released 9 years ago.
- you can memory map in a 120 MB and use no heap at all.  This might be a more efficient approach however
- the memory consumed is almost certainly what you do with the data which is likely to be many times the size of the file. I wouldn't assume that you are actually only using 120 MB to process this file.

I suggest you memory profile the application with plenty of memory, using eh 64-bit JVM if you have to to understand where the memory is consumed.

Comment: thanks. I have already done what you suggest about profiling the app with 2GB in 64 bits, on doing the operation it took like 270mb from the Eden Space, in 32 bits the max Eden space is like 250Mb, but the tenured pool is still having like 600MB free.
I understand your other suggestion about moving that allocation to native memory, but that code is out of my control (it is a library).
All I want is to understand the reason of this.
Thanks again!

Comment: @Ruben you can trigger the jvm to take a heap dump at the point you get an OOME this should make it clearer as to what is using the space at that point